# Setting up a Windows 7 Virtual Machine on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have my original Windows 7 Professional installation disks "for distribution only with a new HP or Compaq pc" and would like to create a Windows VM on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation. I've looked at VirtualBox, but I couldn't get it to work as it wanted an ISO disk, not my original disks. 
Does anyone have any suggestions? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your DVD drive to the VM, or make an ISO of the DVDs. In the settings of the VM:
[image]

Note the small image of a CD  next to the drop-down list. Click it and select your Host Drive. You don't need to enable Passthrough. To create a disk image, open Brasero, and use the "Disk Copy" option.

Comment: For installing a VM from a DVD, I just create a VM, stick the install disk in the DVD drive, and in the prompt or under 'Devices' chose 'Host Drive...'